# UITableView only pushes to one controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, navigationcontroller

So I have my UITableView, with 2 sections and 1 cell in each, and if I click the first one, it works, then the second one, it goes to the first controller. RootViewController is a navigationController, trying to push to ViewControllers.

Here's the code for the tableView:

```
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
        return @"Terminal/SSH Guides";
    }else{
        return @"Cydia Tutorials";
    }
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.text = @"Changing Password for root";
    } else {
        cell.text = @"Hiding Sections";
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id newController;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            newController = [[rootpassword alloc] initWithNibName:@"rootpassword" bundle:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            newController = [[hidingsections alloc] initWithNibName:@"hidingsections" bundle:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:TRUE];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
}
```

I'm also having trouble adding more sections and rows/cells to sections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should do the switch in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" over indexPath.section instead of indexPath.row since both sections have only one row.

Comment: That seems to work, but what if I wanted to add more sections and more than one row to each? Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to do that depending on the data you have. Usually you will have a switch on the section an array foreach section with the data to configure the cell. Checkout this example http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/

Comment: Ah, thanks. Managed to get it working with a some if/switch loops.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one row in each section, so indexPath.row will always be zero.  In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have to test the section not the row (presuming you intend to keep only one row per section).